# How to use two domains going to different websites? Hamachi and XAMPP

Tags: apache, dns, xampp, hamachi

```
Hello everyone what I need help with is how to make my domains go to the correct htdocs.
Here is where I am at and what I am getting stumped on.

myfirstdomain.local and myseconddomain.local both work the first one goes to htdocs and my          second one goes to htdocs2 like it should, what I am trying to do now is make it so other people/friends view it also I am using hamachi so I don't have to deal with port forwarding. What I am asking is how can I make it so www.mysite.net (which works goes to my htdocs/website) but my www.mysite2.tk redirects back to www.mysite.net how can I make it so www.mysite2.tk goes to htdocs2? Where other people can type in my .tk domain and go to that website I made in htdocs2? I really would like to learn how to do this since I love coding but I don't want to have to do www.mysite.net/otherwebsite I just want it so I can have two sites with two different domains.
```

I have fixed it this if anyone needs help please feel free to message me.